# How do I generate a unique id from an auto incremented integer?

Tags: hash, hashcode, uniqueidentifier

I have an auto incremented id (an int) that I want to convert in to something less "mine-able". Basically I don't want people to be able to access data/0, data/1, data/2, etc. and rip through our entire database. I was thinking of just hashing the ID but I wasn't sure if I could guarantee uniqueness.

Let's say the value range is from 1 to a couple hundred million. It may be that one of the hash algorithms can guarantee uniqueness within those parameters.

If not, what would be a good approach to take?

I did consider hashing and then appending the ID.

I'm trying to avoid using a GUID because it would require a lot of changes to existing code so I'd prefer to transform the data I have.

EDIT:

To further explain the situation - these are static resources that are being hit. I don't have to go to a database and reverse it or look it up against something else. Imagine a listing of products - a user might have a link to a specific page but I don't want them to be able to programatically go through every page so I need an non incrementing ID.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know hashing is intended to create unique ID based on some concrete data (e.g. name, surname etc.). Hashing auto incremented ID wont help you much. If someone searches through your database by entering an auto incremented ID, that ID will be passed to hash function as parameter and he will still get the data he wants. So I think that better solution would be to hash some other data in order to get a unique ID. If you do so then a person who searches through you database would have to know exact data that is stored in there (e.g. He would have to know exact name of you employee, or his SSN).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use something pseudo-random to salt the value before hashing if there is no need for reverse lookup.